# Hide certain running app icon in plank

Tags: plank

Recently i installed Notejot apps from AppCenter then run it, then i want to hide the icon from plank without closing the app so the widget would stick on my desktop.
If we unchecked "show unpinned" from plank preferences it will hide all the unpinned apps when the apps running, instead of that, is it possible to hide just certain running app (in my case just Notejot app) icon from plank?

Comment: It doesn't appear that it's possible to do what you're asking. Plank will show an icon even if there isn't a desktop file for the application (unless "show unpinned" is disabled). Perhaps submitting a wishlist item [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/plank) will help.

Comment: @mr.k99 I see, i've asked it in the launchpad.